# How can i programmatically get the url of a "Page" located in "Pages" library? SharePoint 2010

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise

I am building a site map using asp:TreeView control, the site map will show a structure consisting of the root site collection, subsites and pages.
I am note able to get the url of those pages so i can navigate to them by clicking on a page TreeNode! This component is being built in a custom web part in SharePoint 2010 and all of my site pages are of "Publishing Site" type.
I could really use some help :-)

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work...

```
//pageListItem is an SPListItem from your "Pages" list
if (pageListItem.File != null) {
  string url = pageListItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
}
```

Comment: Perfekt! You just solved the problem. Thanx Andrew Petersen & Andrew Adamich i appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

you should take your SPListItem - which is a page and get SharePoint "FileRef" field. This should be something similar to:

```
string[] pageUrlLookUp = list.Items["FileRef"].ToString().Split(new[] { ";#" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

if (pageUrlLookUp.Length > 1)
   pageUrl = "/" + pageUrlLookUp[1].TrimStart('/');
```

where list is your page library

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: Sir, Thanks for the fast response!

Two things:

1. When i run the code, it throws an exception that says "Field with name 'FileRef' was not found."

2. It's `list.Items.Fields["FileRef"]...` and not `list.Items["FileRef"]...`

SharePoint UI doesn't show that the page file have any field named 'FileRef' which should hold the url to the page.

/Eliya